# Why can't "Binary operator '==' be applied to two 'dispatch_queue_t!' operands"

Tags: swift

I receive the error `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'dispatch_queue_t!' operands` when I do this:

```
let mySocketQueue = dispatch_queue_create("SomeNameHere", nil);
if mySocketQueue == dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0) {
    print("same")
}
```

How am I supposed to compare these two dispatch_queue_t! types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `==` operator for `dispatch_queue_t`.

However, since it is a *reference type*, you can use the ["identical-to" operator `===`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Operators/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/opfunc/s:ZFSsoi3eeeFTGSqPSs9AnyObject__GSqPS____Sb) to check if
two constants or variables refer to the same single instance:

```
if mySocketQueue === dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0) {
    print("same")
}
```